# "Opening output file: permission denied", -rw-r--r--

Tags: linux, permissions

**TLDR:** Why is "permission denied"?!?!?!

In Emacs, upon `C-x C-c`, I get prompt

```
Save abbrevs in ~/.emacs.d/abbrev_defs? (y or n)
```

Typing `y`, I get

```
Opening output file: permission denied, /home/iam/.emacs.d/abbrev_defs
```

Checking permissions, I find

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1737 Jun 28 08:51 abbrev_defs
```

**Question:** What is going on here? If Emacs wants to save abbrevs, shouldn't I want it too? Why can't I? Permissions seem correct? User seems to have read-write permissions. What am I missing?

Comment: And the question is ....?

Comment: @Xavierjazz, why would I want permission denied? Isn't this undesirable? I realize it's not clear as stated, but is this right? Why is permission denied despite `-rw`? How can I fix this, if it is advisable?

Comment: The way this site generally works, things need to be clearly stated. As it is now there is no question which opens it up to being closed. Edit your "question" to include a clear question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root is granted read and write permissions, as root owns the file.  User iam has only read permissions.

`chown iam /home/iam/.emacs.d/abbrev_defs` and it will re-posessed by iam, and thus be accessible with read/write permissions.

Comment: As others stated in comments to the question, you should still clarify your original question, as it is off topic in current form.  This answer is to the only thing I can sensibly guess from what you wrote is likely the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Of course! Now that the issue seems clear, I've removed what were probably the extraneous parts. Curious that this file was only writable by root. I'll have to keep an eye out for why that happened.

Comment: I should have said, "...was *owned* by root."